# validate options[] with isset

Tags: php, arrays, validation, isset

Hey i am having some trouble getting an options[] array to work, if anyone can help that will be great
Form

```
<form method="post" action="array2.php">
<select name="options[]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The array2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['options[]'] == "" ){
        header("Location: error.html");
        exit; 
    }else{
        $checked = $_POST['options'];
        $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be great, also what happens is even if it's an empty feild, the thing progress's to the rest of the script

rest of script

```
    <?php
    for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
        echo "You have selected to recive " . $checked[$i] . " tickets<br/>";
    }
    for($i=0; $i < count($checked2); $i++){
        echo "And you have selected to recive " . $checked2[$i] . " for accommodation are you sure? <br/>";
    }
?>
```

Sorry I am unable to reply to people for now soon as I posted it a class came to the empty room so need to wait an hour :/

Comment: Do you want to allow a multiple choice?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, no i dont want multiple choice's on an array tutorial i was on they said [] was required for drop down list to work, soon as i took it out, it worked, never going to trust something online again </3 lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the change your `options[]` to `option` as it mean you are submitting multiple select with the same name

```
<form method="post" action="array2.php">
<select name="options">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

in your `array2.php` file

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['options'] == "" ){
        header("Location: error.html");
        exit; 
    }else{
        $checked = $_POST['options'];
        $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
    }
}
?>
```

if you really need to send `options[]`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(is_array($_POST['options']){
    if($_POST['options'][0] == "" ){
        header("Location: error.html");
        exit; 
    }else{
        $checked = $_POST['options'][0];
        $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
    }
  }else{
    if($_POST['options'] == "" ){
        header("Location: error.html");
        exit; 
    }else{
        $checked = $_POST['options'];
        $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

you can clean this if else as you like

Comment: thank you for the reply, sorry i am so late in getting back, yes this is what i am after, sadly i wasnt wanting multiple choices to be selectable, i fell foul to the php youtube video's never getting a tutorial that way again lol idk he said it was a must that [] was there, total spaz moment should have realised that was the main issue from teh start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example code

```
<?php 
    if($_POST) { 
        if(isset($_POST['state'])) { 
            if($_POST['state'] == 'NULL') { 
                echo '<p>Please select an option from the select box.</p>'; 
            } 
            else { 
                echo '<p>You have selected: <strong>', $_POST['state'], '</strong>.</p>'; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

and your html code

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <legend>Please select a state</legend> 
        <select name="state"> 
            <option value="NULL">-- Please select a state --</option> 
            <option value="AK">AK - Alaska</option> 
            <option value="AL">AL - Alabama</option> 
            <option value="WY">WY - Wyoming</option> 
        </select> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry i am so late in replying back this works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in your case options[] can be used for sending multiple fields as array, the index starts with 0, for example:

```
<input name="test[]"> : index 0

<input name="test[]"> : index 1
```

then, you can get these values in $_POST['test'] like this:

```
$input_one = $_POST['test'][0];
$input_one = $_POST['test'][1];
```

if you look at this inside $_POST it will be like this:

```
$_POST = array (
...,
'test' => array(0=> ..., 1 => ...)
)
```

for your form, if you only had one options[], then the value is the $_POST will be

```
if(isset($_POST['options'][0])){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's clean it up

```
<select name="options">
```

You do not need options[].

And then the result of `$_POST['options']` will be the value of option. And add there `<option value="0">Select</option>` and then check whether the POSTed data is higher then 0

Answer (score 0):

in html

```
<select name="options">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
.
.
```

in php

```
    if(isset($_POST['options']) && !empty($_POST['options'])) {
      $checked = $_POST['options'];
    }
```